# C Makefile given two .o files

Tags: c, makefile

I am given two .o files with their respective header files. util.o and weatherio.o. I am trying to create a makefile for my project, but I can't seem to figure it out. I created two additional c files main.c and analyze.c. analyze includes util.h and weatherio.h while main includes analyze.h. This is the makefile I currently have but it is not working.

```
analyze: main.o analyze.o util.o weatherio.o
    cc analyze.o main.o util.o weatherio.o -o analyze
analyze.o: weatherio.h util.h analyze.c analyze.h
    cc -c analyze.c 
main.o: main.c analyze.h
    cc -c main.c
```

Comment: What happens if you execute make?

Comment: It will compile it, but only if I don't use any function that's in weatherio or util. For example if I call a function from util inside analyze it will not compile and says there is an undefined reference to the function I called. I am using Netbeans ide

Comment: I don't use NetBeans, but can you modify the makefile so you see that your change takes effect (add an extra option, such as `-I/I/am/here` and look for that in the output from the compilation).  If you don't see that even when you're compiling and linking, then NetBeans isn't using the same makefile that you think it is using.

Comment: Yeah I can see when I am making changes to the makefile. EDIT: Well I copied everything over from Netbeans and used cygwin to make and it seems to be working fine. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: It sounds as if `util.o` and `weatherio.o` do not contain what you've been told they contain. Do you have `objdump`?

Comment: As suggested by @Beta, please use 'objdump -S weatherio.o util.o' to confirm that the function declared in weatherio.h / util.h which is called from main.c are defined in respective .o (object files) given to you. Also, are you getting linking error 'file format not recognized' for *.o files provided to you while doing make?