# Linking two .o files together

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, 64-bit, nasm

I have two .asm files, one that calls a function inside the other. My files look like:

mainProg.asm:

```
 global main
 extern factorial

    section .text
main:
;---snip---
    push rcx
    call factorial
    pop  rcx
;---snip---
    ret
```

factorial.asm:

```
    section .text
factorial:
    cmp rdi, 0
    je  l2

    mov rax, 1
l1: 
    mul rdi
    dec rdi
    jnz l1
    ret

l2:
    mov rax, 1
    ret
```

(Yes, there's some things I could improve with the implementation.)

I tried to compile them according to the steps at [How to link two nasm source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187028/how-to-link-two-nasm-source-files):

```
$ nasm -felf64 -o factorial.o factorial.asm
$ nasm -felf64 -o mainProg.o mainProg.asm
$ gcc -o mainProg mainProg.o factorial.o
```

The first two commands work without issue, but the last fails with

```
mainProg.o: In function `main':
mainProg.asm:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `factorial'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Changing the order of the object files doesn't change the error.
I tried searching for solutions to link two .o files, and I found the question [C Makefile given two .o files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292634/c-makefile-given-two-o-files). As mentioned there, I ran `objdump -S factorial.o` and got

```
factorial.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <factorial>:
   0:   48 83 ff 00             cmp    $0x0,%rdi
   4:   74 0e                   je     14 <l2>
   6:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax

000000000000000b <l1>:
   b:   48 f7 e7                mul    %rdi
   e:   48 ff cf                dec    %rdi
  11:   75 f8                   jne    b <l1>
  13:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000014 <l2>:
  14:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  19:   c3                      retq
```

which is pretty much identical to the source file. It clearly contains the `factorial` function, so why doesn't `ld` detect it? Is there a different method to link two .o files?

Comment: You need to make `factorial` a global symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `global factorial` assembler directive in `factorial.asm`.  Without that, it's still in the symbol table, but the linker won't consider it for linking between objects.

A label like `factorial:` is half way between a global/external symbol and a local label like `.loop1:` would make (not present in the object file at all).  Local labels are a good way to get less messy disassembly, with one block per function instead of a separate block starting after every branch target.

Non-global symbols are only useful for disassembly and stuff like that, AFAIK.  I think they would get stripped, along with debug information, by `strip`.

---

Also, note that `imul rax, rdi` [runs faster](http://agner.org/optimize/), because it doesn't have to store the high half of the result in `%rdx`, or even calculate it.

Also note that you can `objdump -Mintel -d` to get intel-syntax disassembly.  Agner Fog's `objconv` is also very nice, but it's more typing because the output doesn't go to stdout by default.  (Although a shell wrapper function or script can solve that.)

Anyway, this would be better:

```
global factorial
factorial:
    mov eax, 1   ; depending on the assembler, might save a REX prefix

    ; early-out branch after setting rax, instead of duplicating the constant
    test   rdi, rdi   ; test is shorter than compare-against-zero
    jz .early_out

.loop:                 ; local label won't appear in the object file
    imul   rax, rdi
    dec    rdi
    jnz .loop
.early_out:
    ret
```

---

Why does `main` push/pop `rcx`?  If you're writing functions that follow the standard ABI (definitely a good idea unless there's a large performance gain), and you want something to survive a `call`, keep it in a call-preserved register like `rbx`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `.` at the beginning of a label made it local; I thought it was just a naming convention that some programmers used. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @luolimao: I updated with some more tips, including tightening up your factorial code.  You didn't say anything about `main` looking at `rdx:rax` as the return value.  You can save an iteration by doing `cmp   rdi, 1` / `jne` in the loop, to avoid multiplying by 1.  Or even unroll the last two iterations to multiply by 2 with a shift.  Probably not worth the extra instructions, though.  Anyway, yeah intel-syntax asm doesn't seem to be documented all in one place anywhere.  Instruction-set stuff is in one place, and assembler directive / label stuff is in the YASM and NASM manuals.

Comment: Ah, I assumed `mul` was faster than `imul` because it was older, but clearly not; your assumption that I don't use `rdx` from `factorial` was correct, too. As far as the `push rcx` is concerned, I started running out of registers (`rbx` holds some other data), and I pushed `rcx` since it's the loop counter (instead of `sub esp, 8`, `call factorial`, `add esp, 8`, and storing the counter in, say, `r12`)

Comment: @luolimao: Oh right, you need to keep the stack 16B-aligned for `factorial`.  Do that with `sub rsp, 8` (not esp!) outside the loop.  (or an odd number of `push`es to save/restore call-preserved registers so you can use them in `main`.)  The goal is to avoid any save/restore overhead inside `main`'s loop: `main` uses call-preserved registers (like `rbx` or `rbp`) in its loop, and the called function hopefully only needs scratch registers.  Having `main` save/restore its loop counter is bad for fast-returning functions: it puts a 5 cycle round-trip to memory in a loop-carried dependency chain.

Comment: If you need to spill a register, prefer spilling one that's holding something you just need to re-load or re-compute later, rather than one you have to save as well as reload.  This is a case where a C compiler could do whole-program optimization and know which registers `factorial` used (i.e. that it doesn't clobber `rcx`), and make non-ABI-compliant functions that take advantage of knowing about each other.  Not recommended for hand-written asm, though, esp. between two files, because of the maintenance / human-readability nightmare.

Comment: I assume you emphasize using `sub rsp, 8` instead of `esp` because it'll zero out the upper 32 bits of `rsp`? Honestly, I've been just using the 64-bit registers in almost all commands (unless I need to move a single byte, or something), because I'm not quite sure when it's better to use the 32-bit ones.

Comment: @luolimao: Yes, clearing the upper32 of `rsp` will make your program segfault the next time you touch the stack.  The default operand size is 32b, so it takes one less byte to encode 32b insns:  A REX prefix is needed for 64b operand-size, or if the insn touches any of r8-r15 (or the low 8b of a register other than [a-d]l, like `sil` or `bpl`).  For almost all instructions, the only performance difference is code-size, and there are more important performance considerations to worry about (esp. when still learning).

Comment: The only perf diff I found in Agner Fog's insn tables for 32 vs. 64b operand-size for Intel Haswell is for `div`/`idiv`, where 64b is much slower.  One-operand `imul`, and `mul`, is actually faster in 64b (one fewer uop).  Perhaps the wiring "naturally" gets the 128b result to `rdx:rax`, and splitting a 64b result into `edx:eax` is what takes an extra uop.  So a good rule of thumb is probably still to always use 32b, except when you know you need 64b.  Generally avoid 16b and 8b unless you want the merging with prev value behaviour. (narrow stores to memory are fine, and movsx loads.)